# Start CS-Script as administrator

Tags: c#, scripting, cs-script

I have some CS-Script with a complex logic, need to start that script as administrator.
I tried to add

```
//css_npp asadmin
```

to the beginning of the script file, it doesnt work, so maybe i do something wrong.
Main point is that i need to specify administrator privileges in the script file, not outside.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to do this so the user doesn't get to approve/deny elevation?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Actually, any solution would be nice. But i can't even get this approve/deny elevation. Just dont know how to provide it.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I'm not specifically familiar with the cs-script stuff, but just wanted to get that clarified so people didn't think you were trying to do something malicious here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i found a solution.

First, you need to be sure that in "cs-script/Lib" or in "yourScriptFolder" there is a file "Elevate.cs". If its not download it from here [CS-Script](https://csscriptsource.codeplex.com/releases/view/125765) (cs-script.ExtensionPack.7z, it will be on the Lib folder), and put the file into the "Lib" folder or into "yourScriptFolder".

Second, write in the beginning of your file

```
//css_inc Elevate.cs;
//css_pre elevate();
```

And it will work!